# jQuery select nth element of this in .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Taking this html structure, I need to grab the selector 3 items back. However, this code is contained in a `.each()` statement and I am using `$(this)`. Not to mention, I am skipping the first 3 items.

So basically, when I get to item #4, I need to select item #1; on item #5, select item #2, and so on.

```
<div id="item-1" class="class">Item 1</div>
<div id="item-2" class="class">Item 2</div>
<div id="item-3" class="class">Item 3</div>
<div id="item-4" class="class">Item 4</div>
<div id="item-5" class="class">Item 5</div>
<div id="item-6" class="class">Item 6</div>
<div id="item-7" class="class">Item 7</div>
<div id="item-8" class="class">Item 8</div>
<div id="item-9" class="class">Item 9</div>
<div id="item-10" class="class">Item 10</div>
```

I am trying to output the id attribute to make sure i have the right one. I have tried `.slice(-3)`, `.eq(-3)`, and many more. The use of 3 `.prev()` in a row does work, but there has to be a cleaner way to do this.

```
$('.class').each(function(i){
  if (i > 2) {
    console.log($(this).prev().prev().prev().attr('id'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this, with and `eq()` this will consider first element to be indexed zero so you need to use `eq(i-3)`

```
$class = $('.class');
 $class.each(function(i){

 if (i > 2)
    console.log( $class.eq(i-3).attr('id'));

});
```

Comment: You could ditch the extra index variable since you already have the index in the function argument. `.eq(i-3)` would be equivalent.

Comment: @j08691 thanks for the suggestion yes it was an axtra thing :)

Comment: It looks like many of these will work, but I accepted this as the answer for what I was doing. It looks like the bulk of my issues was trying to work with `$(this)` to traverse in reverse

Answer (score 3):

Cache the selection, slice away the first 3 and then index the collection directly.

To log the ID, just use the `.id` property of the DOM element.

```
var cls = $('.class');
cls.slice(3).each(function(i, el){
  console.log(cls[i].id, el.id);
});
```

```js
var pre = $("pre")[0];

var cls = $('.class');
cls.slice(3).each(function(i, el) {
  pre.textContent += cls[i].id + ", " + el.id  + "\n";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item-1" class="class">Item 1</div>
<div id="item-2" class="class">Item 2</div>
<div id="item-3" class="class">Item 3</div>
<div id="item-4" class="class">Item 4</div>
<div id="item-5" class="class">Item 5</div>
<div id="item-6" class="class">Item 6</div>
<div id="item-7" class="class">Item 7</div>
<div id="item-8" class="class">Item 8</div>
<div id="item-9" class="class">Item 9</div>
<div id="item-10" class="class">Item 10</div>
<pre></pre>
```

Or without jQuery:

```
var cls = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
[].slice.call(cls, 3).forEach(function(el, i){
  console.log(cls[i].id, el.id);
});
```

```js
var pre = document.querySelector("pre");

var cls = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
[].slice.call(cls, 3).forEach(function(el, i){
  pre.textContent += cls[i].id + ", " + el.id  + "\n";
});
```

```html
<div id="item-1" class="class">Item 1</div>
<div id="item-2" class="class">Item 2</div>
<div id="item-3" class="class">Item 3</div>
<div id="item-4" class="class">Item 4</div>
<div id="item-5" class="class">Item 5</div>
<div id="item-6" class="class">Item 6</div>
<div id="item-7" class="class">Item 7</div>
<div id="item-8" class="class">Item 8</div>
<div id="item-9" class="class">Item 9</div>
<div id="item-10" class="class">Item 10</div>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: I was in the middle of suggesting you supply context to explain to him what this is doing, and you updated it. This is a good solution now, and should perform well..

Comment: Move your slice to the selector, not the .each. Index mismatch. Edited the solution to correct it. Oh, and he wants to get the element 2 up from this one. Err... I jumped to conclusion. The solution isn't 100% complete based on that.

Comment: @Daved: Actually I had just forgotten to include jQuery. :-D It's actually working since the indices will be a subset representing the first 7. He can use the second parameter to pair the other element if needed.

Comment: Well, then ignore my edit ;) I think I need to step away for a few and pace myself. ^_^

Comment: @Daved: That's alright. I think I confused both of us. :-)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but in the scope of the `.each()`, `$(this)` is equivalent to the item 3 back, and not the item called on? As in, on the item in the `.each()` itteration, I want to add a attribute equal to the attribute on the item 3 back.

Comment: @Tregonia: `cls[i]` refers to the one that is 3 back and `el` (or `this`) refers to the current one. Because of the `.slice()`, we're actually iterating starting on the fourth element, but our indexing still starts at `0`, which is why we use `cls[i]` on the original (non-sliced) set.

Comment: ...for that matter, you could just use `for(var i = 0; i < cls.length-3, i++) { console.log(cls[i].id, cls[i+3].id); }` This would be the fastest way.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I missed the inclusion of the `el` when i wrote that reply

Answer (score 0):

So you can use:

```
$('.class').each(function(i){
  if (i > 2) {
    console.log($('.class').eq(i-3).attr('id'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain your answer a bit for the OP and future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

you should try following:

```
$('.class').slice(0,-3).each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```